# Reconnection strategy in Mule ESB

Tags: http, mule, mule-studio, reconnect

I am trying to verify the Reconnection strategy in Mule ESB as mentioned in the documentation.

I have set the standard Reconnection strategy with retry attemts as 5 and with some timeout.

(My end point is not reachable, as intentionally stopped it to test the scenario).

I have the exception in the Mule console as:
Exception stack is:
1. Connection refused: connect (java.net.ConnectException)
  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint

And then I changed the reconnection strategy to 'connect forever' and tried it.
In this case also I got the same error.

My qstn is, if I set the 'Connect forever' feature, then I expect the application to try for re connect untill it gets succeeded. but this is not happenning.

And also in the first scenario, if my retry attemps are 5, then I dont see any loogs mentioning the number of retry attempts made.

Can any one plese explain it in better way whether this reconnection property is actually working in Mule ESB 3.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What transport are you reconnecting? JDBC? JMS?

Comment: My endpoint is an HTTP/SOAP webservice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP is a disconnected protocol: the reconnection strategies only work for connected protocols, like JMS or JDBC.

I see the error is in an outbound endpoint so I have the impression you are expecting Mule to **retry** the dispatch, not **reconnected** the transport.

One way to do retries is to use the `until-successful` message processor.

Comment: But, I see in the studio the HTTP endpoint has also Reconnection property.         And also any Idea how we can achieve re try in case of Http endpoints in mule, I need to try limited attempts not untill successful.    Thanks

Comment: Reconnection on HTTP endpoints is meaningless, I reckon Studio displays a standard property pane here.

Comment: @DavidDossot is FTP a connected protocol like JMS and JDBC, I assume yes can you confirm please ?

Comment: @Sudarshan as far as I can tell from the source code, only the FTP inbound endpoint would be reconnected.

Comment: Sorry don't get you in the above answer you make a distinction between connected and disconnected protocols, I am trying to understand where FTP stands ?

Comment: @Sudarshan Let's take this discussion to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746247/which-mule-transports-does-the-re-connection-strategy-work-with